# Как сделать, чтобы парсило текст до определенного момента?

Tags: python, парсер, xpath, xmlparser

```
import requests
from lxml import etree
import lxml.html
import csv

def parse(url):
    api = requests.get(url)
    tree = lxml.html.document_fromstring(api.text)
    text_news = tree.xpath('//*[@id="newslist"]/div/div/div/div/a/span/text()')
    text_date = tree.xpath('//*[@id="newslist"]/div//*[@class="time"]/text()')
    print(text_news)
    print(text_date)

parse('https://24.kg')
```

Вот код, вот сайт который парсю https://24.kg

Я хочу спарсить заголовки новостей, и время этих новостей (на сайте все видно, посмотрите). Все выходит, но есть одно но, я хочу спарсить новости именно на сегодня, а у меня парсится текст и время и на сегодня, и на вчера. Как сделать так, чтобы парсило текст до определенного момента, т.е. не весь, а только на сегодня который?

Comment: а разве дата того что вы парсите не регулируется xpath, оторый вы передаете в text news и text_date? Смотрите, на сайте указано время публикации новости. Вам нужно выстроить  xpath таким образом, чтобы захватывать эту дату, далее анализировать и захватывать новости только попадающие под нужную вам дату... как-то так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужны новости только за сегодня, то все просто:

Начинайте парсинг вместо:

```
*[@id="newslist"]
```

с уровня блока:

```
div[@class="lineDate"]
```

первый такой по счету блок и будет требуемым, так как новости располагаются в хронологическом порядке.